# Using networkd with linux namespaces

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming, systemd, linux-namespaces

I am currently trying to simulate a network using network namespaces under Linux. I have already set up the nodes and connected them, and they can ping each other, one hop at a time. But I am really struggling trying to enable IP forwarding.

I am using Ubuntu Server 21.04 and networking on my system is controlled by systemd-networkd. systemd's version is `247.3-3ubuntu3.4`. `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding` and `net.ipv4.ip_forward` are already enabled.
Because networkd is used, forwarding has to be enabled in configuration files additionally.
For one of my namespaces, this looks as follows:

/etc/systemd/network/router1i.network:

```
[Match]
Name=router1i

[Network]
IPForward=yes
```

and
/etc/systemd/network/router1i2.network:

```
[Match]
Name=router1i2

[Network]
IPForward=yes
```

Those (`router1i` and `router1i2`) are both veth interfaces and the only 2 interfaces in the namespace.

If I use the command `ip -6 route get to fe80::1:0:200 iif router1i2` in the namespace, I get the correct answer `fe80::1:0:200 from :: dev router1i2 proto kernel metric 256 iif router1i2 pref medium`, because the route doesn't involve forwarding. If I use the similar command `ip -6 route get to fe80::1:0:200 iif router1i` that starts from the other interface, the answer suddenly is `RNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`. So apparently, forwarding isn't enabled.

I already tried to get networkd to update by using `networkctl reconfigure router1i` from within the namespace, but it says `Failed to reconfigure network interface router1i: No such device or address`. This is strange, because when I use `networkctl status router1i`, it lists all the information correctly. A full reload using `networkctl reload` was also already tried and doesn't change anything.

I'm out of ideas. I don't even necessarily need to get it to work with networkd. What can I try next?

Comment: I think you just have a route conflict. Do `ip -6 route show` and `ip -6 addr show`.  Also where are the other side of the `veth` pairs for each?  if `router1i2` is paired with `router1i1` then your traffic is looping back to the same namespace.

Comment: This question is already resolved. I also asked it on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662859/ip-forwarding-in-linux-namespaces)